# Python Script for Raspberry Pi not running properly

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, new-operator

im having a little trouble with a python script that I wrote the other day. This script is for my rasbperry pi that has a digital interface attached to the GPIO pins.  The purpose of this script is to test and see if it will unlock a electromechanical lock for 5secs.  Though when I run the script nothing happeneds.  There are no errors being logged and being new to python scripting im not sure what the problem is.  Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

I know there's nothing wrong with the digital interface and raspberry pi interaction becuase i can run python manually with the commands below, and everything works like it should.  The lock release and then I can turn it off.  Though when I run my script nothing happeneds.

```
python
import piface.pfio
piface.pfio.init()
piface.pfio.digital_write(0, 1)
led0 = piface.pfio.LED(0)
led0.turn_off()
```

My python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Door Lock: System to control an electric lock"""

import piface.pfio as piface
from time import sleep

class AuthToken:
    def _init_(self, id, secret):
        self.id=id
        self.secret.secret

class TestDoorController:
    def send_open_pulse(self):
        print "unlock the door"

class BasicAuthenticator:
    id = "Andrew"
    secretPassword = "1234"
    def check(self,token):
        print "checking input of '" + token.id + "', + password + : " + token.secret + ", against secret password'" + self.secretPassword +"'"
        result = (token.secret == self.secretPassword) & (token.id == self.id)
        print "authentication is: " + str(result)
        return result

class TestInput:
    def getInput(self):
        print "checking for input"
        authToken + AuthToken("Andrew","1234")
        return authInput

class DoorControllerPiFace:
    def send_open_pulse(self):
        piface.digital_write(0,1)
        sleep(5)
        piface.digital_write(0,0)

def main():
    authInput = TestInput()
    authenticator = BasicAuthenticator()
    doorController = DoorControllerPiFace()

    if(authenticator.check(authInput.getInput())):
        doorController.send_open_pulse()
    if _name_ == '_main_':

        main()
```

Now im getting that the constructor takes no argument?

File "door_controllerTEST.py", line 47, in 
    main()

File "door_controllerTEST.py", line 43, in main
    if(authenticator.check(authInput.getInput())):

File "door_controllerTEST.py", line 30, in getInput
    return AuthToken("Andrew","1234")

TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Added in the extra _ to my AuthToken class and it was giving me a error that my pfio wasnt initialized yet.  so I added in

```
import piface.pfio as pfio
pfio.init()
```

And everything is working after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class TestInput**

The function `getInput(self):` is not returning anything (i.e. the variable `authInput` is empty).

You probably want to return the created token? `return AuthToken("Andrew","1234")` that is.

**Class BasicAuthenticator**

This class checks against `self.id` and `self.secretPassword` but they are not set. You are setting `id` and `secretPassword`.

**Main**

Your main functions isn't called either, should be `if __name__ == '__main__':` with double underlines.

```
class AuthToken:
    def __init__(self, id, secret):
        self.id=id
        self.secret=secret

class TestDoorController:
    def send_open_pulse(self):
        print "unlock the door"

class BasicAuthenticator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = "Andrew"
        self.secretPassword = "1234"

    def check(self,token):
        print "checking input of '" + token.id + "', + password + : " + token.secret + ", against secret password'" + self.secretPassword +"'"
        result = (token.secret == self.secretPassword) & (token.id == self.id)
        print "authentication is: " + str(result)
        return result

class TestInput:
    def getInput(self):
        print "checking for input"
        return AuthToken("Andrew","1234")

class DoorControllerPiFace:
    def send_open_pulse(self):
        piface.digital_write(0,1)
        sleep(5)
        piface.digital_write(0,0)

def main():
    authInput = TestInput()
    authenticator = BasicAuthenticator()
    doorController = DoorControllerPiFace()

    if(authenticator.check(authInput.getInput())):
        doorController.send_open_pulse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your right I accidentally put that in there but even after adding in the new lines, nothing is going on.  Its still running and not giving me any output.

Comment: Try changing to double underscores in `if _name_ == _main_:` and you will get some output :)

Comment: Added in the double comments and now im at least getting some messages.  I put them in the description above.  And dont i define self.id to be id or am I miss reading that

Comment: You are also missing double underscores in init for AuthToken class, check the code in my answer, should work.

Comment: I added the description above and everything is working like it should now.  Since being new to python was adding in these extra lines and good thing to do?  Im just curious